# Using T-SQL for Grouping, concatenating and counting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table Product of two columns ProductID & DefectCode as shown to the left, i need to summarize data to group by ProductID and Concatenate DefectCode and also count the number of recurrence of each code as shown to the right
I managed to group and concatenate using the following code but couldn't count recurrence of each Defect code

```
  select ProductID,

          ISNULL(STUFF(
         (SELECT distinct '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10), DefectCode) 
          FROM Product
          WHERE ProductID=a.ProductID
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '') ,'') AS Defects

from Product as a

group by ProductID
```

Sample data to left and required result to right
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation in the subquery:

```
SELECT p.ProductID,
       ISNULL(STUFF( (SELECT CONCAT('-', p2.DefectCode, '(', COUNT(*), ')')
                      FROM Product p2
                      WHERE p2.ProductID = p.ProductID
                      GROUP BY p2.DefectCode
                      FOR XML PATH ('')
                     ), 1, 1, ''
                   ), '') AS Defects    
FROM Product p
GROUP BY p.ProductID;
```

I assume you are using an older version of SQL Server that doesn't support `STRING_AGG()`.